# Differing amount of Columns in matrix, way to use each individual column in analysis equations?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm generating matrix's that vary in amount of columns they have, and I need to apply some equations to each of these columns and store their results separatly (different columns in a new matrix would be fine).  For my first equation I am taking sections of the matrixs and using those to do some analysis, for example:

```
A1 = interpolate((817/2+.5):(908/2),:);
B1 = interpolate((909/2+.5):(1000/2),:);

averageB = sum(B1)/length(B1);
averageA = sum(A1)/length(A1);

tapWithSign = (averageB - averageA) / (averageB + averageA / 2) * 100;

tapA1B1 = abs(tapWithSign);
```

I tested what I have currently and it pulls those specific sections correctly into a new matrix.  The issue comes in when I try applying them into the equation.  it just gives me a single value when i should have 13 values (13 values if i have 13 columns i need evaluating)

Comment: From the look of your first code sample, `tapA1B1` is going to be single value. How are you applying it to several columns?

Comment: For the second code sample, what is it that you want it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: I only did the first set.  I actually go up to A11 and B11 with the whole thing.  And i know tapA1B1 is going to be a single value, i normally have 11 values at the end of the sequence, but this is with only 1 column of data.  I now have 13 columns in one matrix that need to be run through so i should have 143 values at the end of it.  (13 columns with 11 rows each)

Comment: For the second code sample, it is going through the entire column (as there is only one in my original set up) and its doing the actions in that statement.  So i have a matrix thats 5448 values in one column.  This code takes it down to 5446 (as the first and last value cant be used).  I now have 13 columns (could be more could be less) and need it to do the same thing as it was doing with a single column, to each column now.  so 13 columns with 5446 values each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
tapWithSign = (averageB - averageA) / (averageB + averageA / 2) * 100;
```

To be sure I have this right: `averageB` and `averageA` are vectors with dimensions (1,13).  You want `tapWithSign` to have same dimensions as these.

What you need to do is

```
tapWithSign = (averageB - averageA) ./ (averageB + averageA / 2) * 100;
```

You need `./` instead of `/`.  `A ./ B` means "divide every element of A by every element of B and put the result in a matrix/vector the same size and shape as A and B."  `A / B` is matrix division, you can read exactly what it is by typing `doc mrdivide` at your matlab prompt.

Once `tapWithSign` has the right dimensions, `abs(tapWithSign)` will as well.

Comment: The only place i forget to do this is the one that matters most =/ lol and such a simple solution.  Thanks so much.  Do you have any input on the second equation?

Comment: @BenB.  Why don't you work on the second equation with the first one fixed, and then come back with a clearer question about it if you still don't have it.  Its too hard for me to guess what you are doing from what is there.

Comment: I'll just re ask about the second part in a new post with clearer needs.  Editing code currently and making changes that i've had so far.  Thanks for this quick little fix.